# How to launch Terminal without using Dash?

Tags: unity-dash, gnome-terminal

I just ran the newest Ubuntu from an USB stick. Now Dash is empty and knows nothing about the contents of the computer.

I found a fix here but to make it work I should be able to open Terminal.

How do I do it without Dash? :)

Answer (score 6):

Try to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and a new terminal window should appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch applications in many ways:

- The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> works often for many user interface (at least unity and lxde)
- The <kbd>Windows</kbd> key or <kbd>Super Key</kbd> on Unity invokes the launcher, then you can launch whatever application you want, for example, the terminal application, start writing "term", then use the down arrow key, and select the terminal application
- The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> permits to run a command (works on gnome, lxde and  kde as far as I remember), then you can write the complete name of the application you want, for example "terminal" or "konsole" if you have it installed